# EasyAlign: Why first line is not aligned?

Tags: alignment, plugin-easy-align

I have below shortcut and function to align code.

```
map <leader>vga :call Vhdl_GA_All()<CR>

" Alignment
function! Vhdl_GA_All()
   exe ":'<,'> EasyAlign *<space>"
   exe ":'<,'> EasyAlign ("
   exe ":'<,'> EasyAlign )"
endfunction
```

Code before alignment:
[image]

Select line 2~4 and run `<leader>vga`
[image]

Why first line is not aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found need to add `exe "normal! \e"` before EasyAlign.

Comment: can you tick your question as answered please?